# Logging Ping information via CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd, ping

I'm currently having connectivity issues and I would like to monitor a certain IP address and log the information.

I know I could use this command (using google.com as an example):

```
ping google.com /t |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > pingORA.txt
```

In this case it will log a ping result every second. I would like it to log a ping result **every 30 seconds**. Is there a way to add this to the above command?

Comment: Does one of these answers resolve the question?

Answer (score 0):

use awk to save every 30th ping result discarding the rest

```
awk '
BEGIN { srand();t=srand();\
while (1 ) {\
  tElapsed=srand()-t;
  if(tElapsed%30==0){\
   print("write to file from here")\
  }\
  print ("pinging google");\
  system("sleep 1");\
 }
 }'
```

Comment: How exactly is this [`cmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmd/info) related?

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems you rather wanted a `powershell` solution, (so I have included the relevant tag as well) You can still do the same in normal `cmd` by using a `for` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ping google.com -t') do echo %a >> pingORA.txt & timeout /t 30 >nul 2>&1
```

Note however, this is directly from `cmd` and not `powershell`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in PowerShell using `Test-Connection`.

```
$hostName = 'localhost'
$waitTime = 30
$logFile = 'pingORA.txt'
if (Test-Path -Path $logFile) { Remove-Item -Path $logFile }

while (1) {
    $p = Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostName -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($null -ne $p) {
        "{0} - {1} - {2}" -f (Get-Date), $hostName, $p.ProtocolAddress |
            Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Encoding ascii -Append
    } else {
        "{0} - {1} - {2}" -f (Get-Date), $hostName, 'offline' |
            Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Encoding ascii -Append
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds $waitTime
}
```